Missing required module 'Testing'
After upgrading to Xcode 16, the UITests target started getting a compilation error: Missing required module 'Testing'.
The problem affects only UITest. In Xcode 15 everything works fine.
Any ideas what can be done?
I tried to connect manually testing framework but the result is the same.
Related thread on swift forum

Hi, did you solve the issue? I was not able to get rid of the error based on @MaxMission answer.

I have the same problem. I noticed one of external dependency swift-snapshot-testing use framework Testing. I have swift-snapshot-testing in local package AppTestUtils. Target AppUITests use AppTestUtils in «Build phases» -> «Link binary with libraries» and was imported in several files. I remove all import AppTestUtils from files for UI tests and it worked. It's strange, but it's not necessary to remove AppTestUtils package from the AppTestUtils target, remove imports is enough.
